# Weblocks loaded with Quicklisp displays only Hunchentoot, not the Weblocks

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp

I followed a Screencast [quicklisp intro 1/2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11wYPAy9qNw) and applied all the steps succesfully on my Mac mini PowerPC, using Clozure CL 1.6 for PowerPC Mac OS. Here are some sample screenchots showing how successful the build has been:

[image: sample 1]
[image: sample 2]
<sub>(source: [hizliresim.com](https://i.hizliresim.com/12YD5b.png))</sub>

But after  `(ql:quickload "weblocks")` running the Weblocks with `(weblocks:start-weblocks)` 
the resulting page shows just the Hunchentoot server and no Weblocks pages in any way, just like that:
[image: sample 3]

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet Another Answer To My Own Question.

On the installation page of [Weblocks website](http://weblocks-framework.info/installation) I noticed some additional steps were being applied starting with:

4. `(ql:quickload :weblocks-demo)`

If you apply this and the following steps, then you can at least get a working "demo" of weblocks working.

Actually that doesn't totally answer why the original Quicklisp intro tutorial cannot display a default Weblocks page, but it should at least put you on the right track.

Comment: As of July 2021, the weblocks site is dead.